# How can I read Greek characters from my database in my web app?

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, encoding, translation

I've got Greek text stored in my access database. For some reason it doesn't appear in Greek- it uses other symbols instead.

e.g. **Ãëþóóá** instead of **Γλώσσα**

I can convert it in my windows app like this:

```
Dim encoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)
Dim valueInBytes As Byte() = encoder.System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(lanuageFilePath)
languageValue = encoder.GetString(valueInBytes)
```

However, I now need to use the values in my web app. But the `ReadAllBytes` method is not available to me. I've tried using `GetBytes` instead, but this doesn't seem to produce the same results.

```
Dim encoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)
Dim valueInBytes As Byte() = encoder.GetBytes(languageValue)
languageValue = encoder.GetString(valueInBytes)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is languageValue a string containing a path to a file or the text to be decoded?

Comment: Sorry, it's the text to be decoded.

Comment: Then the example windows app code is wrong

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've corrected it now.

Comment: Your still reading in from a file in the windows app rather than converting the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one seems to have nothing to do with text in a variable, your reading from a file.

```
Dim encoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)
Dim valueInBytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(languageValue)
languageValue = encoder.GetString(valueInBytes)
```

ReadAllBytes should be supported in most frameworks so there should not be a problem with this on the server.

The other code seems to be doing soething compleatly different. You are converting the string to bytes and back again in the same encoding, to get this to work you need to find out which encoding access thought it was and encode with that. However it may still not have survived the roundtrip as access may be doing some normalistion of the unicode.

```
Dim encoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1253)
Dim accessencoder As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding({{accesses encoding numer here}})
Dim valueInBytes As Byte() = accessencoder.GetBytes(languageValue)
languageValue = encoder.GetString(valueInBytes)
```